# Minimizing quadratic objective under orthogonality constraints

Tags: matrices, oc.optimization-and-control, orthogonal-matrices, qcqp

The following problem is motivated from [Generalized Procrustes Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Procrustes_analysis). I am wondering if it is possible to obtain a closed form minimizer (which may involve SVD or some other decomposition of a known matrix).

---

Given a matrix $\Omega \in \Bbb R^{nd \times m}$,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{R_1, \dots, R_n \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}}{\text{minimize}} & \left\| \begin{bmatrix} R_1 & R_2 & \cdots & R_n \end{bmatrix} \Omega \, \right\|_{\text{F}}^2\\ \text{subject to} & R_i^T R_i = I_d, \quad \forall i \in [n]\end{array}$$

In words, $R_i$ is a $d \times d$ real orthogonal matrix for all $i$.

---

It seems that a closed form solution may not be possible. I would really appreciate pointers to approximation algorithms with guarantees.

---

**Case of** $n=1$. The problem is reduced to
$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{R_1\in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}}{\text{minimize}} & \left\| R_1 \Omega \, \right\|_{\text{F}}^2\\ \text{subject to} & R_1^T R_1 = I_d\end{array}$$

In this case, $\left\| R_1 \Omega \, \right\|_{\text{F}}^2 = \text{tr}(R_1\Omega\Omega^TR_1^T) = \text{tr}(R_1^TR_1\Omega\Omega^T) = \text{tr}(\Omega\Omega^T)$. So, any orthogonal $R_1$ would minimize the objective.

---

**Case of** $n=2$. The problem is reduced to
$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{R_1, R_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}}{\text{minimize}} & \left\| \begin{bmatrix} R_1 & R_2 \end{bmatrix} \Omega \, \right\|_{\text{F}}^2\\ \text{subject to} & R_i^T R_i = I_d, \quad \forall i \in [2]\end{array}$$

Write $\Omega$ as $\begin{bmatrix} \Omega_1\\ \Omega_2 \end{bmatrix}$ where $\Omega_i \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times m}$. Then the objective is

$$\begin{align}
&\left\|R_1\Omega_1 + R_2\Omega_2\right\|_F^2\\
&= \text{tr}((R_1\Omega_1 + R_2\Omega_2)(R_1\Omega_1 + R_2\Omega_2)^T)\\
&= \text{tr}(R_1\Omega_1\Omega_1^TR_1^T + 2R_1\Omega_1\Omega_2^TR_2^T + R_2\Omega_2\Omega_2^TR_2^T)\\
&= \text{tr}(\Omega_1\Omega_1^T) + 2\text{tr}(R_1\Omega_1\Omega_2^TR_2^T) + \text{tr}(\Omega_2\Omega_2^T)
\end{align}$$

Using the SVD $\Omega_1\Omega_2^T = U\Sigma V^T$, the objective is reduced to

$$\begin{align}
&= \text{tr}(\Omega_1\Omega_1^T) + \text{tr}(\Omega_2\Omega_2^T) + 2\text{tr}(R_1U\Sigma V^TR_2^T) \\
&= \text{tr}(\Omega_1\Omega_1^T) + \text{tr}(\Omega_2\Omega_2^T) + 2\text{tr}(V^TR_2^TR_1U\Sigma)
\end{align}$$

This is minimized when $V^TR_2^TR_1U = -I$ i.e. $R_1U = -R_2V$. So, the optimal solution is, choose any orthogonal $R_1$ and then $R_2 = -R_1UV^T$.

---

**Idea for general** $n$.

As in the case of $n=2$ we write $\Omega$ as $\begin{bmatrix} \Omega_1\\ \vdots\\ \Omega_n \end{bmatrix}$ where $\Omega_i \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times m}$. Then the objective is reduced to

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\text{tr}(\Omega_i\Omega_i^T) + 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\text{tr}(R_i\Omega_i\Omega_j^TR_j^T)
\end{align}$$

Then, using SVD, $\Omega_i\Omega_j^T = U_{ij}\Sigma_{ij}V_{ij}^T$. As in the case of $n=2$, the objective is then reduced to,

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\text{tr}(\Omega_i\Omega_i^T) + 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\text{tr}(V_{ij}^TR_j^TR_iU_{ij}\Sigma_{ij})
\end{align}$$

It is minimized when $V_{ij}^TR_j^TR_iU_{ij} = -I$ i.e. $R_iU_{ij} +R_jV_{ij} = 0$ for all $i,j \in [n], i \neq j$. So one would like to solve this system of equations for $R_i$'s. However, in general, it may have no solution.

Comment: I should disappoint you somewhat: even when $d=1$, i.e., we are talking about minimizing the absolute value of the sum $\sum_k r_k\omega_k$ with real given $\omega_k$ and $r_k=\pm 1$, there is no much better option than to consider all choices of signs, so no "closed form" is really in sight and I doubt that your minimization procedure really converges to anything like the true minimizer unless $n$ is really small (2 or 3). Just test it in the following way: take any $\Omega$ for which the value $0$ can be attained and see how close you can come to it. :-)

Comment: @fedja Thanks for the reply. It does seem that a closed form solution may not be possible. Your discussion for the case of $d=1$ (and suppose $m=1$) reminds me of the balanced partition problem which can probably be solved by a deterministic algorithm. However, the case of $d=1$ and $m>1$ seems difficult. You're right, my minimization procedure is greedy and it surely does not converge to the true minimizer.

Comment: What are the typical values of $d,m,n$ you are considering? The only really easy case is $n=2$ and you can use it to do *something* but I would prefer to test it myself before recommending anything to avoid being similar to that rabbi from the sick cow story :-)

Comment: $n=2$ is not enough. Typical values are $d=2$ or $3$, $n=100$ and $m=10^4$.

Comment: $n > 2$ seems challenging.

Comment: *"$n>2$ seems challenging."* Exactly. As you noticed yourself, $m$ is not of great importance because we just need to minimize the sum of traces in which all matrices are $d\times d$. But $n=100$ is really a headache: I hoped for $n\approx 10$ :-(. Can you describe your current algorithm to use it as a benchmark to compare any alternatives to?

Comment: @fedja The above is a simplified form of a modified version of the GPA objective (see Eq 1 in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0924271602000436) . My algorithm provides an approximate solution to the original problem. Clearly the original problem has a more intuitive formulation. However, I would like to focus on the above problem.

In short, take it for now that I have no algorithm to solve the above problem. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of the little Grothendieck problem.

- Afonso Bandeira, Christopher Kennedy, Amit Singer, [Approximating the little Grothendieck problem over the orthogonal and unitary groups](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10107-016-0993-7) [[PDF]](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Eamits/publications/Grothendieck_published.pdf), Mathematical Programming, 160(1), Pages 433-475, 2016.